# Issue with dynamically drawing multiple svgs on image with onMouse events due to viewport positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

everybody! Right now I am struggling with a new project of mine. The goal is to have an image rendered as a React component and then drawing boxes with SVG on top of it. To achieve that I have set positioning to absolute in the respective CSS file. I want to attach an onMouseOver function to each of the boxes drawn and this is where I have an issue:

I need to move the viewPort of the SVG to only the box drawn because otherwise, the onMouseOver function will trigger as soon as I hover over the image as well as when I enter the rectangle. This is because I can only attach the function to the SVG viewPort not to the rectangle directly. Whenever I move the viewPort of the SVG this setting will be "ignored" due to the absolute positioning in CSS. As the rectangle will be drawn dynamically based on fetched data (not implemented right now) I cannot hardcode the position in CSS.

Please find the code sandbox here: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-dan-5j4gg2?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx%3A44%2C13&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00082067yyucpq1x%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00032067tx5o5izs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00052067sduc73ol%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00072067vdw8l200%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clp5ihe0k00032067tx5o5izs%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00032067tx5o5izs%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clp5ihu3s004y2067kgqlarxn%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0j00022067qro4cftn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihu3s004y2067kgqlarxn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.module.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5inqx501f92067gkhymx3m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clp5ihe0k00072067vdw8l200%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00062067r01csjkj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00072067vdw8l200%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00062067r01csjkj%2522%257D%252C%2522clp5ihe0k00052067sduc73ol%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00042067opraairw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00052067sduc73ol%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clp5ihe0k00042067opraairw%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

And here is the code for the sample:

```
import React from "react";
import { SVGProps } from "react";

const SvgComponent = (props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 750 2050" {...props}>
    <rect
      x={190}
      y={300}
      width={300}
      height={200}
      style={{
        fill: "none",
        stroke: "darkred",
        strokeWidth: "10",
        pointerEvents: "visible",
      }}
    />
  </svg>
);

export default () => (
  <div>
    <SvgComponent
      onMouseOver={() => {
        console.log("Mouse over detected");
      }}
    />
    <img src="https://wallup.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06/338054-landscape-Sun.jpg" />
    <style>
      {`
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0:
      }
    `}
    </style>
  </div>
);
```

I tried to condense the problem as much as possible so that it easy to reproduce. Thanks to everybody who can help me out on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution which is way easier that I originally anticipated. You can hook onto the rectangle itself which allows for exactly the behavior I wanted to achieve. Here is the corrected code for you:

```
import React from "react";
import { SVGProps } from "react";

const SvgComponent = (props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 750 2050" {...props}>
    <rect
      x={190}
      y={300}
      width={300}
      height={200}
      style={{
        fill: "none",
        stroke: "darkred",
        strokeWidth: "10",
        pointerEvents: "visible",
      }}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        console.log("Mouse over detected");
      }}
    />
  </svg>
);

export default () => (
  <div>
    <SvgComponent />
    <img src="https://wallup.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06/338054-landscape-Sun.jpg" />
    <style>
      {`
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0:
      }
    `}
    </style>
  </div>
);
```

I hope I can help out someone who faces the same issue as I did